# Why does the background color only change after a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a user logs in, the background of their liked photos should change. Why does the background color only change when the page is reloaded and not after a successful login? There are too many requests happening at the same time and I don't know how to handle them properly. Maybe someone has any ideas.?

**Login.js**

```
import { useAppContext } from "../context/appContext";

function Login() {
  const { handleClick } = useAppContext();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Log in</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

**Home.js**

```
import { useAppContext } from "../context/appContext";

function Home() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("landscape");
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const { token, username, getUserProfile, getToken } =
    useAppContext();

  const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_KEY;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.search.includes("code=") && !token) {
      getToken();
    }

    if (token) {
      getUserProfile();
    }
  }, [token]);

  const fetchImages = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    let params = {
      page: page,
      query: query,
      per_page: 30,
    };

    let headers = {};

    if (username) {
      headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      };
      
    } else {
      params = { ...params, client_id: clientId };
    }

    axios
      .get("https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos", { headers, params })
      .then((response) => {
        setImages([...images, ...response.data.results]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages();
    setQuery("");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Login />
      {loading && <Loader />}
      <ImageList images={images} fetchImages={fetchImages} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

**appContext.js**

```
import React, { useReducer, useContext } from "react";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import axios from "axios";
import {
  SET_TOKEN,
  SET_USERNAME,
  LOGOUT_USER,
} from "./actions";

const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
const username = localStorage.getItem("username");

const initialState = {
  token: token,
  username: username,
};

const client_id = process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_KEY;
const redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000/";
const api_auth_uri = "https://unsplash.com/oauth/authorize";
const api_token_uri = "https://unsplash.com/oauth/token";
const response_type = "code";
const scope = [
  "public",
  "read_user",
  "write_user",
  "read_photos",
  "write_photos",
  "write_likes",
  "write_followers",
  "read_collections",
  "write_collections",
];
const client_secret = process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_SECRET;
const grant_type = "authorization_code";

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    window.location.href = `${api_auth_uri}?client_id=${client_id}&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}&response_type=${response_type}&scope=${scope.join(
      "+"
    )}`;
  
  };

  const getToken = async () => {
    const coder = window.location.search.split("code=")[1];
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        `${api_token_uri}?client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}&code=${coder}&grant_type=${grant_type}`
       
      );
      const { access_token } = data;
      
      localStorage.setItem("token", access_token);

      dispatch({
        type: SET_TOKEN,
        payload: { access_token },
      });
      const newUrl = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
      history.replaceState({}, document.title, newUrl);
    } catch (error) {
      logoutUser();
    }
   
  };

  const getUserProfile = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.unsplash.com/me`, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + state.token,
        },
      });

      const { username } = data;
      localStorage.setItem("username", username);

      dispatch({
        type: SET_USERNAME,
        payload: { username },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  };

  const logoutUser = () => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_USER });
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        handleClick,
        getToken,
        getUserProfile,
        logoutUser,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

export { AppProvider, initialState, useAppContext };
```

**ImageList.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../styles/ImageList.scss";

function ImageList({ images }) {
 
  return (
    <div className="result">
          {images?.map((image, index) => (
            <div
              style={{
                backgroundColor: image.liked_by_user ? "red" : "",
              }}
              key={image.id}
            >
                <div key={image.id}>
                  <img src={image.urls.small} alt={image.alt_description} />
                </div>
            </div>
          ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImageList;
```

Comment: The `key` prop should be on the `<div>` with the `style` prop

Comment: Sorry, was your question about background colors or too many concurrent API requests?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description. My main question is about the background color.